# What is the correct StoreLogo images configs, sizes for app icon for app on Microsoft Windows Store?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, microsoft-store

I exported the images following the doc: https://www.electron.build/configuration/appx.html#appx-assets.

4 required images are used:

Logo: StoreLogo.png

Square150x150Logo: Square150x150Logo.png

Square44x44Logo: Square44x44Logo.png

Wide310x150Logo: Wide310x150Logo.png

However the installed app icon is not taking up all icon background area leaving a black background:

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?